# Probability proof and combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I was asked to use the factorial definition of ${m \choose r}$ to verify that the equalities hold: $${n \choose k}k = {n \choose k-1}(n-k+1) = n {n-1 \choose k-1}$$

The answer is 
\begin{align*}
{n \choose k}k &= \frac{k! n!}{(n-k)! k!} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)! (k-1)!} \\
 {n \choose k-1}(n-k+1) &= \frac{(n-k+1)! n!}{(n-k+1)! (k-1)!} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)! (k-1)!} \\
n {n-1 \choose k-1} &= \frac{n(n-1)!}{(n-k)! (k-1)!} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)! (k-1)!} 
\end{align*}

But I can't see how, for example, from $\frac{k! n!}{(n-k)! k!}$ we get $\frac{n!}{(n-k)! (k-1)!}$. Why this is not $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: $k \neq k!$ unless $k$ equals $1$ or $2$. So, proof-read the first line of what you claim is the answer.

Comment: @Dilip Actually, the $k!$ in the numerator on the first line and the $(n-k+1)!$ on the second line are typos.  Upon removing the extraneous "!", all is well.

Comment: @whuber I am quite aware of where the problems arise and what needs to be done. I was hoping that the OP would react to my comment and discover the typo(s) for him/her self. (The issue does not arise in the third of the three proofs.

Comment: Nice! So the answer sheet was wrong! Now I understand the problem!

Comment: @Dilip Sorry; I wasn't trying to imply you weren't aware: your comment showed you understood the issues. My comment was intended to help the OP avoid a possible misunderstanding of your comment, which could cause the reader to focus on the *second* equality in each line without noticing the blatant typographical errors that occurred at the *first* equality.

Comment: I have rolled this question back to its original form because the corrections added in the edit make it incomprehensible: without the typographical errors, there's no question here at all and the comments make no sense.